# editor for javascript, xsl, xhtml and css, other than aptana or xcode?

Tags: javascript, css, xslt, xhtml, editor

It is a good thing if this is opensource, much better if it is multi-OS.

I used to use XCode for mac, and I find it quite interesting as an editor. But I don't like how it handles the "projects" (I hate when suddently you find new folders and files in your code folder).

Needing to work with windows, I've tried aptana. It seems that when building a project, it just reads the content without writting anything. It is much cleaner for me. But I find it heavily loaded with characteristics that I do not need, and I really miss the find/replace features of XCode, where all the matches are automatically marked on the document, and the "folding" versatility of XCode also vs the aptana possibilities.

Then I've though that maybe I was missing some key program out there. Any suggestions?

(thanks)

Comment: You note that a plus is multi-OS, but what is the primary platform you need the editor for? Windows?

Comment: mainly macOS, but I work with both so although I would prefer one for both, I anyway have to have one for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is a better question than the one I'm about to link to, but the answers should be about the same:

> [HTML +CSS +Javascript Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163376/html-css-javascript-editor)

Comment: Actually, it is. I didn't know about netbeans for instance. Thanks for pasting this link :)

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, I'd recommend Notepad++.  Also works on Linux with Wine.  Very minimal, yet powerful.  Free, and open source.  See my own review at http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2007/10/notepad.html.  Excerpt:

> I've been doing quite a bit of JavaScript coding lately, and the
>   desire for a good code editor quickly becomes apparent.
>
> The two main features I was looking for were capable syntax
>   highlighting and code folding. (While other languages such as Java and
>   C++ are commonly supported, many other editors seem to lack good
>   support for JavaScript.)
>
> Notepad++ does both of these nicely, does them by default, and does
>   them well. Additionally, it is free and open source, with a GNU GPL
>   license.
>
> Other useful features included are:
>
> - Search and replace using Regular Expressions.
> - "Find in Files". Handy for searching for a string or pattern across multiple files and directories.
> - Block-select mode / rectangular block selection. Select and manipulate columns of characters, without selecting the entire row(s).
> - Bracket matching, auto indentation, and compiler integration.

Comment: I have used sporadically notepad++, and I will give it a try again. But if my memory is not wrong, I would say there is no way to have a kind-of file explorer integrated. In any case, thank you for remembering it.